# How to replace string with a command in linux

Tags: linux, sed, rhel, docker

If there is any string found with the name "dockerCmd" in a text file, needs to be replaced with a command "docker run -v /doesnt/exist:/foo -w /foo -i -t ubuntu bash"

Environment: Linux

Comment: What is the string you need to replace? What is the "name of the string"? Is it a variable like `dockerCmd=somevalue` and you want to replace `somevalue`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use sed

```
sed -i 's#dockerCmd#docker run -v /doesnt/exist:/foo -w /foo -i -t ubuntu bash#g' file
```

Options

```
 -i
```

edit files in place

```
s#
```

Substitution, used for replacement

```
#g
```

Global flag, if you get more than one result per line, all will be changed.